# How to parsing DialogFlow dates (@sys.time-period) in Java

Tags: java, date, dialogflow-es

I am having an issue parsing DialogFlow dates in Java.
DialogFlow allows us to use words to describe date period entities like "Christmas Eve", "afternoon", "next week", etc. (See https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/docs/reference/system-entities)

However, when I use a term like "Christmas Eve", Dialogflow v2 returns the following object:
{"startDate": "2019-12-25T12:00:00-05:00", "endDate" : "2019-12-18T12:00:00-05:00"}.

Why does DialogFlow return that period for "Christmas Eve"?

With that, what is the best way to parse a date without the offset using LocalDateTime?
For example, given "2019-12-25T12:00:00-05:00", I would like the time to remain as "12:00:00"

I tried using the following code:

```
DateTimeFormatter isoDateFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ISO_DATE_TIME;
LocalDateTime date = LocalDateTime.parse(dateStr, isoDateFormatter);
Date myDate = Date.from(date.atZone(ZoneId.of("UTC")).toInstant());
```

However, the new date is adjusted to return "Wed Dec 25 07:00:00 EST 2019"
How do I fix this to remove the offset without specifying a specific timezone?

Comment: Use `OffsetDateTime` for parsing?

Comment: With ```OffsetDateTime```, won't I have to hard-code the offset? How do you remove the offset without hard-coding it?

Comment: Your date string has offset of `-5:00`, you don't need to hardcode anything.

Comment: Wouldn't I have to say I'm offsetting by "-5:00"? That's hard-coding. What if the offset changes on the date?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by that. You hardcoded the string with that offset? No? then that's not "hardcoding" anything.

Comment: I recommend you don’t use `Date`. That class is poorly designed and long outdated. Also a `Date` (despite its name) is a point in time, it cannot be a date and time of day. Instead use `LocalDateTime` as you already mentioned.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### You’re already there

Your parsing into `LocalDateTime` is correct. And a `LocalDateTime` is just that: a date and time without time zone. Isn’t that exactly what you want? Then just keep that and forget everything about the `Date` class. It’s poorly designed and long outdated anyway.

### If you need an old-fashioned java.util.Date for a legacy API

Sometimes we do need a `Date` for a legacy API not yet upgraded to java.time, the modern Java date and time API. Unfortunately a `Date` isn’t a date and time without time zone. Instead it is a point in time (but without time zone alright). We can only pretend. And we do need to specify a time zone or offset for the conversion.

```
    Instant myInstant = date.atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toInstant();
    Date myDate = Date.from(myInstant);
    System.out.println(myDate);
```

Example output:

> Wed Dec 25 12:00:00 EST 2019

`date` is the `LocalDateTime` from the code from the question.

I am exploiting the fact that a `Date` grabs the JVMs default time zone and uses it for rendering the string it returns from `toString()`, which is implicitly called when we print the `Date`. Many find this behaviour quite confusing. But while you didn’t get the result you asked for, it at least looks like you did. Except the time zone abbreviation is still printed.

Comment: He's getting time with TZOffset there, it's not right to just parse into `LocalDateTime` directly, as that breaks when local offset doesn't match whatever offset he's got in the string. Most strict way here is to parse into `Zoned` or `Offset`, then convert to system default TZ keeping same instant, and only then do a `toLocalDateTime()` from there.

Comment: @M.Prokhorov *I would like the time to remain as "12:00:00"* I understood that the questioner didn’t want to keep the point in time, but exactly the date and the hour of day. Maybe he can correct me.

Comment: It's just I myself would consider an "eve" as something that does have a time compontent, and thus an offset. But there's an option of parsing using `ISO_OFFSET_TIME`, but into a `LocalDateTime`, which ignores the offset. but this thing does need quite a lot of clarification to get right.

Comment: Thanks @Ole V.V. That helps to remove the time-zone. I'll accept this as the answer and try to get someone from the Dialogflow team to answer the issue with incorrect date-periods.

Comment: A tip, wait a couple of days before accepting an answer. Questions without an accepted answer tend to get more attention, and I don’t think it’s too late for someone else to add something that I haven’t written. (Accepting an answer eventually is good style, of course.)